# Symbol differentation in Wolfram Programming Lab gives recursion error

Tags: evaluation, recursion

I was experimenting with the [Wolfram Programming Lab](https://www.wolfram.com/programming-lab/), but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried running this code in a notebook:

```
D[x^2, x]
```

but it gives the error

```
$RecursionLimit: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of 2x.
```

and gives this as the output (the `x` after the `∂` is subscript):

```
Hold[$UserPre[∂x x^2]]
```

It offers the button "release hold", but clicking that doesn't solve the problem. I get the same recursion error and slightly different, though still bizarre, output:

```
Hold[$UserPre[ReleaseHold[Hold[$UserPre[∂x x^2]]]]]
```

Even just typing `2 * x` gives a recursion error. My understanding is that Wolfram Language is designed around symbolic computation, so why isn't this working?

Comment: It sounds like at some point in the past you have probably ran code that is interfering. To test that theory, you could try running a different piece of code like `D[xxxx^2, xxxx]`. If that works, you’ve probably redefined `x` somewhere. The quickest way to solve the problem is probably to go to the Evaluation menu and select Restart Session. This should clear any lingering definitions.

Comment: Huh, I didn't think that would be the issue since I created fresh notebooks before and they reproduced the issue, but I tried again now and it worked. I still feel confused about why creating a fresh notebook didn't work before, but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also, I don't think I ever defined `x` before, so I'm not sure if that could have caused it.

Comment: Camelid, creating a “fresh notebook” does nothing to change the current session or alter the condition of the kernel. Simply put, if you have defined `x` previously & then open a new notebook, this `x` will remained defined because you are still in the same session or using the same kernel.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this. It was either a user error or a possibly serious bug. If ever you are able to replicate this, please report it along with steps to reproduce (even if it only happens say every so often).